# Taking object as input from User in C++

Tags: c++, oop

Actually, I want to pass an object to function by taking input from User. There are many objects and I want user to tell which object to pass. One way that I can think of is by using if/else-if statements (e.g if user says 1(int) then it means object-1). But is there any direct method by which I can directly take object as input. So I can pass it to function without using if/else-if statements.

Comment: Create an array of objects, and then let the user specify the index of the object to work with.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. "Taking object as input from User" sounds like filling the members of an object with data given by the user. Howerver, the rest of the question appears like the user can only select from a list of pre-existing objects. Maybe both? It's unclear.

Comment: Just to make it Clear: Suppose you have a list of objects and you have to pass one of these objects to a function. I want the user to pick out the object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a user input an object directly out-of-the-box, but you can certainly write code to obtain that result (for example by implementing deserialization and receiving a JSON representation of the object).

However, if I understood your question correctly, you have a predefined set of objects with known integer keys. In that case, the most straightforward way is to store these objects in a container, such as [`std::map<int, YourObject>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (or an [`std::vector<YourObject>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if your keys are easily mappable to `[0;N)`). Once you've had the user input the key, you can then lookup into the container to retrieve the corresponding object via the container's `at()` member function.